# Send an Email using Alamofire and Mailgun with Email body as HTML

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, mailgun

I am trying to sead an email from backend from ios Swift app using Alamofire and Mailgun as suggested in

[mailgun.swift](https://gist.github.com/makzan/11e8605f85352abf8dc1)

But i want to output HTML in my email..Below is my code

```
let key = "dfasewr4353terf34t43fefdf34r"

let EmailBody  = "<html><body><table border='1'><tr><td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>50</td></tr><tr>td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94</td></tr><tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>80</td></tr></table></body></html>"

let parameters = [
  "from":from@fromme.com,
  "to": to@tome.com,
  "subject": "my Email Subject",
  "text": EmailBody  
]


Alamofirerequest(.POST, "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/<MAILGUN-DOMAIN>/messages", parameters:parameters)
  .authenticate(user: "api", password: key)
  .response { (request, response, data, error) in
    println(request)
    println(response)
    println(error)
  }

And on click of the button, i get the email and the email body is still in HTML.I dont get Html tables but normal HTML text output as below

Output:

<html><body><table border='1'><tr><td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>50</td></tr><tr>td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94</td></tr><tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>80</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Required output

[image]

Comment: did you try to send the email body via the `html` key instead of the `text` key, as suggested [here](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#examples)

Comment: you get only one API key from Mailgun. I think it has got nothing to do with the key.

Comment: @lootsch.. Thanks a lot for the clue.The link you provided helped me to get there

Answer (score 1):

Change text to html in the parameters and it works like charm

let parameters = [

"from":from@fromme.com,

"to": to@tome.com,

"subject": "my Email Subject",

"html": EmailBody
]